# call a c++ function with char* from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, clr, static-libraries

I have a CLR C++ dll that wrraped a static C++ library.
I have the following class:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>

#include <LibEx.h>
using namespace System;
#using <mscorlib.dll>

namespace LIB_WrapperNamespace {

    public ref class LIB_WrapperClass
    {
    public:
        BOOL WINAPI T_LibEx_ConsoleConnect(IN DWORD num1, IN LPWSTR Name)
        {
            return LibEx_ConsoleConnect(num1,Name);
        }
        };
}
```

in C#, I add the reference to library

```
LIB_WrapperNamespace.LIB_WrapperClass myLib = new LIB_WrapperNamespace.LIB_WrapperClass();
```

Now how to call this function, how to send string to char*? from C#:

```
string myName = "NAME";
myLib.T_LibEx_ConsoleConnect(1,**myName**);
```

Comment: change string to character array

Comment: You can just pass it as a `string` - the Marshaller will handle turning it into a char* for you.

Comment: @Saksham how would that help?  He is defining this in native code, if he used a native array it would still be exposed as a pointer value

Answer (score 2):

The API should be exposing that parameter as a `wchar_t*` hence you need to provide a pointer value in C#.  Try the following

```
IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
try { 
  ptr = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni("NAME");
  unsafe { 
    myLib.T_LibEx_Consoleconnect(1, (char*)(ptr.ToPointer()));
  }
} finally { 
  if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero) { 
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately though since you have exposed the method with a raw pointer value there is no way to use this from C# without a `unsafe` code.  An alternative approach would be to expose an overload which takes say a `string^`.  This would be usable from C# and the C++/CLI code could take care of the marshalling from `string^` to `LPWSTR`

```
BOOL WINAPI T_LibEx_ConsoleConnect(DWORD num1, String^ Name) { 
   IntPtr ip = Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(Name);
   BOOL ret = T_LibEx_ConsoleConnect(num1, static_cast<LPWSTR>(ip.ToPointer()));
   Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ip);
   return ret;
}

// From C#
myLib.T_LibEx_ConsoleConnect(1, "NAME");
```

Comment: I get erro:
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.IntPtr' to 'char*'

Comment: @Joseph ah, you made need to use unsafe code then and use the `IntPtr::ToPointer` method.

Comment: @Joseph I updated my answer to fix the pointer conversion and provide an alternative which doesn't require any unsafe code

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but this time i get:Error 111 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void*' to 'char*'

Comment: @Joseph fixed a small typo.  Which project are you getting that error from (C# ar C++ one)?  I have a local sample which does this and works so it may just be some other typo that I'm missing

Comment: I upload the project, remove everything to make it easy, pls take a look, I have one function, I have one class, add the dll to C# project as reference try to call this function.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/10xa0eoeetibyou/LibWrapper.zip

Comment: @Joseph i think i see what I did wrong.  Try looking at my answer again.  I inserted a necessary cast

Comment: using the String^ in the DLL, allow me call the function directly from C# , I verify I get the string in the DLL. now I'm not sure static_cast<LPWSTR>(ip.ToPointer()) is the correct casting since the Lib return Error, debug I see that T_LibEx_ConsoleConnect get bad data

Comment: @Joseph sorry I'm having a terrible day for typos.  The C++/CLI code should have used `StringToHGlobalUni` not `StringToHGlobalAnsi`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I create a native DLL and use DllImport :

[DllImport("LibEx.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern BOOL T_LibEx_Consoleconnect(DWORD num1, string Name);

Answer (score 0):

Why building C++\CLI project to wrap something when you "expose" marshaling problems onto the user of your wrapper? The idea of C++\CLI is to hide the marshaling troubles inside the wrapper. You should declare the function natively for .NET:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h> 
#include <vector>

namespace ClassLibrary2 {
public ref class Class1
{
public:
    //Expose .NET types to .NET users.
    System::Boolean T_LibEx_ConsoleConnect(System::UInt64 num1, System::String^ Name);
};
```

}

And implementing this wrapper function you marshal as you feel proper, it could look like this:

```
#include "ClassLibrary2.h"

namespace ClassLibrary2 {
System::Boolean Class1::T_LibEx_ConsoleConnect(
    System::UInt64 num1, 
    System::String^ Name)
{
    //Initialize marshaling infrastructure. You can use its instance many times 
    //through out life span of your application.
    msclr::interop::marshal_context^ marshalContext = gcnew msclr::interop::marshal_context();

    //Turn System::String into LPWSTR. Keep in mind that you are now the owner of 
    //memory buffer allocated for unmanagedName. You need to release it somewhere.
    const wchar_t* clsConstChars = marshalContext->marshal_as<const wchar_t*>(Name);
    LPWSTR unmanagedName = const_cast<LPWSTR>(clsConstChars);

    //System::UInt64 num1 will be marshalled to DWORD natively by compiler.
    return LibEx_ConsoleConnect(num1, unmanagedName);
}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I could not compile ClassLibrary2, I get this error:
error C4996: 'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type>::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not included.  Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Indeed the marshal_context does not accept LPWSTR as generic argument, my bad. I replaced the call on to wchar_t*.